# Mysql8 fail to upsert generated uuid

Tags: mysql, upsert

I have a mysql8 table with 2 columns: `ID`(Int) AND `UUID`(Varchar36):

```
CREATE TABLE `upsert_test` (
  `ID` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'id;',
  `UUID` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

I need to mimic the `upsert` behavior without unique-index, and finally I got the following sql command, which works fine with mysql 5.7:

```
INSERT INTO upsert_test
SELECT 1 AS ID, UUID() AS "UUID"
FROM upsert_test
WHERE ID=1
HAVING COUNT(*)=0;
```

However when upgraded to mysql8.0, only a null UUID is inserted, as flowing:

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM upsert_test;
+------+------+
| ID   | UUID |
+------+------+
|    1 | NULL |
+------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And if I execute the `select` sub-command, I do get a valid UUID (this query is actually executed before inserting any data):

```
mysql> SELECT 1 AS ID, UUID() AS "UUID"
    -> FROM upsert_test
    -> WHERE ID=1
    -> HAVING COUNT(*)=0;
+----+--------------------------------------+
| ID | UUID                                 |
+----+--------------------------------------+
|  1 | a1fbea94-f6c4-11eb-903c-0242ac110002 |
+----+--------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

And it just can't be inserted.
And if I ignore the `HAVING` part:

```
mysql> INSERT INTO upsert_test
    -> SELECT 2 AS ID, UUID() AS "UUID";
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.02 sec)
Records: 1  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> SELECT * FROM upsert_test;
+------+--------------------------------------+
| ID   | UUID                                 |
+------+--------------------------------------+
|    1 | NULL                                 |
|    2 | 033e03f7-f6c5-11eb-903c-0242ac110002 |
+------+--------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

We can see that a valid UUID is inserted.

I've been struggling with this issue for this whole afternoon, just can't figure out what the problem is.

Comment: Seems you already have a column so `HAVING COUNT(*)=0` will prevent from inserting. Try `HAVING COUNT(*)=1`

Comment: I tried `HAVING COUNT(*)=1`, and I don't think that's the problem. the new line is indeed inserted without failure (because there is no data in the table before executing the insert command), however the inserted UUID is `NULL`.

Comment: What is the intended purpose of the `WHERE ID=1 HAVING COUNT(*) = 0;` part?

Comment: I need to `upsert` the data (if the row where `ID=1` exists, then the new line should not be inserted), and I'm not able to use `unique-index` for some reasons (there would be null values in the unique-index columns). @mechanical_meat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone answered this question on [stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/297687/mysql8-fail-to-upsert-generated-uuid), so I just copy and paste it here:

You need a subselect to have a valid row with both values

```
    CREATE TABLE `upsert_test` (
      `ID` int unsigned DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'id;',
      `UUID` varchar(36) DEFAULT NULL
    )
```

```
    INSERT INTO upsert_test
    SELECT *  FROM
    (SELECT 1 AS ID, UUID() AS "UUID"
    FROM upsert_test
    WHERE ID=1
    HAVING COUNT(*)=0) t1;
```

```
    SELECT * FROM upsert_test

    ID | UUID                                
    -: | :-----------------------------------
     1 | 63b0fa5b-f6d1-11eb-871d-00163e64f9cc
```